# Drawing from the distribution of a vector of i.i.d. random variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to draw `P` realisations in Matlab of a `1x4` random vector `(X,Y,Z,W)` where `X,Y,Z,W` are i.i.d. random variables (mutually independent and identically distributed) all uniformly distributed in `[0,1]`.

Is `rand(P,4)` doing the job? In particular I am worried about the mutually independent part.

Comment: From the [docs](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html) `rand: uniformly distributed random numbers between 0 and 1`... what implies that they would be dependent on each other? *How* would they be dependant on each other?

Comment: Further: `"The sequence of numbers produced by rand is determined by the internal settings of the uniform pseudorandom number generator that underlies rand"`